# How can I convert a Base64 string to GifImageView?

Tags: android, base64, imageview, gif

I am trying to convert a Base64 string to a GifImageView in Android by doing this:

```
val decodedString: ByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64gif)
val decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)
mExerciseGif.setImageBitmap(decodedByte)
```

However, it is only displaying what it seems to be the first frame of the gif. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible do convert a Base64 string to a Gif in Android?

Comment: Of course. It does not matter what was base64 encoded in that string. If you decode it base64 you get the original back. It is as simple as that.

Comment: By the way: the title and first line of your post are nonsense as one cannot base64 encode a view or an ImageView or a GifImageView. But one can base64 encode a gif image file.

Comment: Apparently you understood the question (although it is a nonsense) and it also seems you have expertise in this area... maybe you can help me reach a solution? Plus, how can I improve the question? Thank you

Comment: *Is it possible do convert a Base64 string to a Gif in Android?* - A Base64 string contains just binary data. A Base64 converter does not care about what is actually encoded in the string, it's just binary data. It's a matter of how you interpret the data after decoding. But it's of course possible that the data in the Base64 string is not what you expect. Try to convert your Base64 string to file (e.g. on https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file) and see if you get what you expected.